# Code first database creation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I have two entities. User and UserContacts.

I have created two classes.
User

```
public class PUser
{
    public int PUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserContact UserContact { get; set; }
}

public class UserContact
{
    public int UserContactId { get; set; }

    public virtual PUser PUser { get; set; }
}
```

I may have multiple user contacts but In my MVC view - I want to add only one user contact.

How can I do that? Above is creating tables but not inserting Puserid in user contact table.

Fluent api used is.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<PUser>()
                .HasOptional(p => p.UserContact).WithRequired(p => p.PUser);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the problem is? Your primary key is missing from the insert?

Comment: Yes, When I do insert. It inserts user contacts but userid goes null.

Comment: Show your code which inserts data.

Comment: Wrote an answer but I don't think your yes was actually a yes. Post your code that adds the item to the DB.

Comment: Did you check `PUsers` table for `UserContact_Id` field?

Comment: Finally, What I did is given ICollection<UserContact> in Puser class and declared PUser virtual property in UserContact. Also declared UserContact in Puser to bind that with view in mvc and not mapped that entity while creating code first. After that while saving; I added user contact in ICollection to save in UserContact.

Answer (score 1):

This is a `one-to-one` relationship, so you need to initialize your `UserContact` when you create `User`. This is how i would do it.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PUser model)//You should use a ViewModel here
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var db = new EfDb(); // If you introduce abstration to you Context, you could avoid this.               
            var user= new PUser
                             {   
                                 Name = model.Name,                                             
                                 UserContact= new UserContact
                                                    {
                                                       Phone = model.UserContact.Phone             
                                                    }
                              };

             db.PUser.Add(user);
             db.SaveChanges();
             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
         }                        
        return View(model);
    }
```